# How to make inverted color uibutton programmatically?

Tags: colors, ios7, uibutton

iOS 7 has been out there for a while now. One thing that I tried to do but unsuccessfully was to replicate the Buy button Apple built into their App Store application.

The buttons have 1 pixel borders and invert the colors when highlighted or selected.

I could make the borders but couldn't make the **inverted colors effect programmatically** without any images.

[image]
[image]

I searched the Internet, but could not find anything useful so far.

Does anyone know how to make this kind of effect for UIButton on iOS 7?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I've got:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

+ (void)setCornerRadius:(CGFloat)radius ofView:(UIView*)view
{
    view.layer.cornerRadius = radius;
    view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}

+ (void)setBorderWidth:(CGFloat)width ofView:(UIView*)view
{
    view.layer.borderWidth = width;
}

+ (void)setBorderColor:(UIColor*)color ofView:(UIView*)view
{
    view.layer.borderColor = [color CGColor];
}

+ (void)styleButton:(UIButton*)button
{
    [Common setBorderWidth:1  ofView:button];
    [Common setCornerRadius:5 ofView:button];

    [Common setBorderColor:[UIColor blueColor] ofView:button];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(button.frame.size, YES, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height));
    UIImage*     image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

Note that this will only work for `UIButtonTypeCustom` buttons.

Of course, if you use another `tintColor` in your app, replace `[UIColor blueColor]`.

Comment: I ended up subclassing UIButton and implemented exactly the same way. I also setBackgroundImage for UIControlStateNormal as well.

Comment: I down voted because LevinsonTechnologies should be the right answer. I've tested it and it works. That is the way it obviously was intended to be done.

Answer (score 2):

You get this functionality for free in IOS when the button is in the "selected" state.

You need to create a routine for the touchUpInside Action for the button.  Inside that routine you have to toggle the "selected" attribute.

```
- (IBAction)touchedFreeButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.freeButton.selected = !self.freeButton.selected;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to avoid this behaviour? I just want to different images without changing the color.